# Using neural networks (MLP) for estimation

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence, perceptron

Im new with NN and i have this problem:

I have a dataset with 300 rows and 33 columns. Each row has 3 more columns for the results.

Im trying to use MLP for trainning a model so that when i have a new row, it estimates those 3 result columns.

I can easily reduce the error during trainning to 0.001 but when i use cross validation it keep estimating very poorly.

It estimates correctly if i use the same entry it used to train, but if i use another values that werent used for trainning the results are very wrong

Im using two hidden layers with 20 neurons each, so my architecture is [33 20 20 3]

For activation function im using biporlarsigmoid function.

Do you guys have some suggestion on where i could try to change to improve this?

Comment: This is just overfitting, please add relevant source code to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Overfitting

As mentioned in the comments, this perfectly describes overfitting.
I strongly suggest reading the wikipedia article on overfitting, as it well describes causes, but I'll summarize some key points here.

#### Model complexity

Overfitting often happens when you model is needlessly complex for the problem. I don't know anything about your dataset, but I'm guessing [33 20 20 3] is more parameters than necessary for predicting.

Try running your cross-validation methods again, this time with either fewer layers, or fewer nodes per layer. Right now you are using 33*20 + 20*20 + 20*3 = 1120 parameters (weights) to make your prediction, is this necessary?

#### Regularization

A common solution to overfitting is regularization. The driving principle is KISS (keep it simple, stupid).

By applying an L1 regularizer to your weights, you keep preference for the smallest number of weights to solve your problem. The network will pull many weights to 0 as they aren't need.

By applying an L2 regularizer to your weights, you keep preference for lower rank solutions to your problem. This means that your network will prefer weights matrices that span lower dimensions. Practically this means your weights will be smaller numbers, and are less likely to be able to "memorize" the data.

What is L1 and L2? These are types of vector norms. L1 is the sum of the absolute value of your weights. L2 is the sqrt of the sum of squares of your weights. (L3 is the cubed root of the sum of cubes of weights, L4 ...).

#### Distortions

Another commonly used technique is to augment your training data with distorted versions of your training samples. This only makes sense with certain types of data. For instance images can be rotated, scaled, shifted, add gaussian noise, etc. without dramatically changing the content of the image.

By adding distortions, your network will no longer memorize your data, but will also learn when things look similar to your data. The number 1 rotated 2 degrees still looks like a 1, so the network should be able to learn from both of these.

Only you know your data. If this is something that can be done with your data (even just adding a little gaussian noise to each feature), then maybe this is worth looking into. But do not use this blindly without considering the implications it may have on your dataset.

#### Careful analysis of data

I put this last because it is an indirect response to the overfitting problem. Check your data before pumping it through a black-box algorithm (like a neural network). Here are a few questions worth answering if your network doesn't work:

1. Are any of my features strongly correlated with each other?
2. How do baseline algorithms perform? (Linear regression, logistic regression, etc.)
3. How are my training samples distributed among classes? Do I have 298 samples of one class and 1 sample of the other two?
4. How similar are my samples within a class? Maybe I have 100 samples for this class, but all of them are the same (or nearly the same).